# Indent button and unordered lists in the WordPress visual editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using the Twenty-Ten theme and just want to know whether the indent button in the Visual Editor actually works for unordered lists because I can seem to get it to add inside the ul tag a padding-left of 90px?

The puzzling thing about this, is that I am using Custom Page Template themes where it all seems to work fine in my "About Us" page and so took this template and made it into another, which is using the same div ids such as "content" and "entry-content".

Comment: This can probably be closed under the typo/unrepro guideline: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved and was due to a WordPress setup error.